# Using sscanf to extract some values

Tags: c

gcc 4.4.2

I have the following code:

```
char channels[] = "NumberOfChannel = [2]";

sscanf(channels, "%*[^=]= %d", &chan);
```

I am wondering what this means. As far as I can tell. It is ignoring the equals sign.

```
'^ ignore the character ='
```

Would that be correct?

Many thanks,

Comment: Actually in sscanf [] is maily used to read a whitespace characters. we can use this like character class in regular expression

Comment: In this statement sscanf  does not read any values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%*[^=]
```

The `[^=]` means match a string which contains no `=`. <del>This is a [POSIX extension](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html).</del> The `*` means discard the matched result.

(BTW, to correctly get `chan` you need `sscanf(channels, "%*[^=]= [%d]", &chan);`.)

Comment: `[^` is described in the C standard available from http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards.html and isn't a POSIX extension.